# Is there a difference between Ubuntu versions

Tags: ros-hydro, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi community

I have currently developed all packages I need using *Ubuntu precise* and *ROS hydro*. 
I know that it could be some hassle to move to *ROS indigo*. 
But can there be any problems involved to move to another *Ubuntu* version? 
Or in other words: **How do I choose the right version of *Ubuntu* to use for my robot?**

Thanks for your help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194321/is-there-a-difference-between-ubuntu-versions/) by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on ROS Answers with karma: 862 on 2014-10-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're developing with Hydro, your best (and only) choice for ROS distribution is 12.04. All other distributions supported by hydro have been EOLed (end-of-life) and are no longer receiving updates. Since precise is LTS, it will be receiving support and updates on the important bits (i.e. libraries, kernel) until 2017.

If you want to take advantage of a newer distribution - 14.04 (supported until 2019), the [migration](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Migration) to indigo for most code is extremely painless.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2014-10-06**:
This means ... if I want to use 14.04,  have to move to indigo - otherwise I stick with 12.04?

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-10-06**:
Yes, that's the case.